Create unique id column for each pair of (col_x, col_y) in polars Python
I have a polars dataframe with subject_id, timestamp, event, col1, and col2 columns.
I want to split this dataframe into two polars dataframe (one with subject_id, timestamp, event and one with subject_id, timestamp, col1, col2), but create a column for a unique id before splitting such that I can use that id to join the split dataframes after grouping/manipulating separately.
How can I create this unique id column in polars where there is a unique id for every unique subject_id, timestamp pair in the dataframe before splitting?
Essentially, I wish to do what this post provided, but in Polars. I understand Polars does not have indexes, so what is the best approach?

Looks like I just had to do a bit more digging - it's helpful to try to find a solution in pandas first then try to replicate using polars. Answer from this post:
(
    # Add row index.
    df.with_row_index()
    # Group on id and cat column. 
    .group_by(
        ["id", "cat"],
        maintain_order=True,
    )
    .agg(
        # Create a list of all index positions per group.
        pl.col("index")
    )
    # Add a new row count for each group.
    .with_row_index("ngroup")
    # Expand index list column to separate rows.
    .explode("index")
    # Reorder columns.
    .select("index", "ngroup", "id", "cat")
    # Optionally sort by original order.
    .sort("index")
)


The example of desired transformation is taken from the pandas post linked in question.
Essentially, if you have a DataFrame like this:
hape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ brand ┆ description ┆ former_price ┆ discounted_price │
│ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---              │
│ str   ┆ str         ┆ f64          ┆ f64              │
╞═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ A     ┆ icecream    ┆ 1099.0       ┆ 855.0            │
│ A     ┆ cheese      ┆ 469.0        ┆ 375.0            │
│ B     ┆ catfood     ┆ 179.0        ┆ 119.0            │
│ C     ┆ NaN         ┆ 699.0        ┆ 399.0            │
│ NaN   ┆ icecream    ┆ 769.0        ┆ 549.0            │
│ A     ┆ icecream    ┆ 769.0        ┆ 669.0            │
└───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┘

You want to get an output where each brand, description is assigned a unique number:
┌───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ brand ┆ description ┆ former_price ┆ discounted_price ┆ product_key │
│ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---              ┆ ---         │
│ str   ┆ str         ┆ f64          ┆ f64              ┆ u32         │
╞═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A     ┆ icecream    ┆ 1099.0       ┆ 855.0            ┆ 2           │
│ A     ┆ cheese      ┆ 469.0        ┆ 375.0            ┆ 1           │
│ B     ┆ catfood     ┆ 179.0        ┆ 119.0            ┆ 4           │
│ C     ┆ NaN         ┆ 699.0        ┆ 399.0            ┆ 5           │
│ NaN   ┆ icecream    ┆ 769.0        ┆ 549.0            ┆ 6           │
│ A     ┆ icecream    ┆ 769.0        ┆ 669.0            ┆ 2           │
└───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────┘

In Polars you can do it with pl.Expr.rank(). You need to do it over multiple columns, so you can use pl.struct() to create a column containing both brand and description, and use min method to use “competition” ranking and assign the same min value to tied elements:
df.with_columns(
    product_key = pl.struct("brand","description").rank(method="min")
)

shape: (6, 5)
┌───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ brand ┆ description ┆ former_price ┆ discounted_price ┆ product_key │
│ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---              ┆ ---         │
│ str   ┆ str         ┆ f64          ┆ f64              ┆ u32         │
╞═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A     ┆ icecream    ┆ 1099.0       ┆ 855.0            ┆ 2           │
│ A     ┆ cheese      ┆ 469.0        ┆ 375.0            ┆ 1           │
│ B     ┆ catfood     ┆ 179.0        ┆ 119.0            ┆ 4           │
│ C     ┆ NaN         ┆ 699.0        ┆ 399.0            ┆ 5           │
│ NaN   ┆ icecream    ┆ 769.0        ┆ 549.0            ┆ 6           │
│ A     ┆ icecream    ┆ 769.0        ┆ 669.0            ┆ 2           │
└───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────┘

